# Codeception Unit test using fullMock

Tags: craft4, tests

I have a custom field for which I would like to write some basic unit tests. I was looking into `fullMock: true` since really don't need a full Craft environment. I want to test the `normalizeValue()` method of my field, but for this I need to mock a few responses from Craft classes (one being `Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsConsoleRequest()`).
I set up the tests according to the basic setup guide here: https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/testing/testing-craft/setup.html but added `fullMock: true` to `codeception.yml`. Now as soon as I do that, any test I set up throws the following error: `Argument #1 ($test) must be of type Codeception\PHPUnit\TestCase, Codeception\Test\TestCaseWrapper given`.
This is my most basic test:

```
namespace tomfrit\fubar\tests;

use Craft;
use Codeception\Test\Unit;
use UnitTester;
use tomfrit\fubar\fields\fubarField;

class FuBarTest extends Unit
{
    protected fubarField $plugin;

    protected function _before()
    {
        $this->plugin = new fubarField();
    }

    public function testSettings()
    {
        $this->assertSame($this->plugin->displayName(),"Horst");

    }
}
```

This should of course fail since the field's name is not Horst but it throws the above mentioned error instead.
As the next step I would like to mock Craft's i18n, getIsConsoleRequest() and the guzzleClient in order to make my tests useful but first I'd be grateful if someone could help me fix this error. (or maybe shed some light if I am running in the completely wrong direction. I am new to PHP/Craft testing, but have a pretty good understanding of jest and react-testing-library)
Thanks!